# Is it possible to see all metrics (all paths) in whisper (graphite)?

Tags: metrics, graphite, whisper

I have a lot of metrics in Graphite and I have to search through them.

I tried to use whisper-fetch.py, but it returns the metric values (numbers), I want the metric names, something like that:

prefix1.prefix2.metricName1
prefix1.prefix2.metricName2
...

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the unix `find` command, e.g. `find /data/graphite -name 'some_pattern'` or use the web api, e.g. `curl http://my-graphite/metrics/find?query=somequery`, see [graphite metrics api](https://graphite-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#the-metrics-api)

Comment: There is no directory called ``/data/graphite`` where I can find my metrics

Comment: Can you tell me if the metric names (those paths) are located in ``.wsp`` files or not? When I use whisper-fetch.py to read those .wsp files, I only get the values (numbers) and not the actual metric names

Comment: the filename of the wsp file is the metric name. replace /data/graphite with the dir where you store the metrics.

Answer (score 2):

Graphite has a dedicated endpoint for retrieving all metrics as part of its [HTTP API](https://graphite-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#metrics-index-json): `/metrics/index.json`

For example, running this command against my local Graphite

```
curl localhost:8080/metrics/index.json | jq "."
```

produces the following output:

```
[
  "carbon.agents.graphite-0-a.activeConnections",
  "carbon.agents.graphite-0-a.avgUpdateTime",
  "carbon.agents.graphite-0-a.blacklistMatches",
  "carbon.agents.graphite-0-a.cache.bulk_queries",
  "carbon.agents.graphite-0-a.cache.overflow",
  ...
  "stats_counts.response.200",
  "stats_counts.response.400",
  "stats_counts.response.404",
  "stats_counts.statsd.bad_lines_seen",
  "stats_counts.statsd.metrics_received",
  "stats_counts.statsd.packets_received",
  "statsd.numStats"
]
```